# LUIS.AI patterns regarding optional punctuation for words vs entity lists work differently from each other than expected

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

Here is a pattern i've created 
`({SeminarsList}|seminar)[s]((list|lists)|(info|information))[(?|.|!)]`

I would expect the optional [s] to work for both entity list and the word i.e. ending with s on seminars such as seminar vs seminars. However, only the entity list works as expected.  the s for seminars is ignore and the pattern isn't recognized for `seminars info`

Is this a bug or something expected.  I would rather it work like the entity list as that makes perfect sense and is the same way reflected in the documentation?

**update**
Also, the word on it's own without being a group works as expected.

so for example this works

`where[(are|is)][the](SeminarsList|seminar)[[']s][seminar][[']s] [(location|locate|located)]`

i.e. the send seminar with optional punctuation works as expected just not in a grouping

Update**

Here is an example from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-tutorial-pattern)

> Select the OrgChart-Manager intent, then enter the following template utterances:
>
> Template utterances
>
> 1. Who is {Employee} the subordinate of[?]
> 2. Who does {Employee} report to[?]
> 3. Who is {Employee}['s] manager[?]
> 4. Who does {Employee} directly report to[?]
> 5. Who is {Employee}['s] supervisor[?]
> 6. Who is the boss of {Employee}[?]

In the above example this is the documentation of how this works.  Including adding "punctuation" to the end of the sentence in an optional format. If one would expect this to work I would also expect the other methodology of working too.

Answer (score 0):

Per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/reference-pattern-syntax) (emphasis mine):

> Pattern syntax is a template for an utterance. The template should contain words and entities you want to match as well as **words** and **punctuation** you want to ignore. It is not a regular expression.

So, the pattern syntax is not meant to be used for single letters, but for full words. It has to due with the tokenization of utterances.

If you'd like this feature added, I'd recommend upvoting [this LUIS UserVoice ticket](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/551524-language-understanding-luis/suggestions/36020344-improve-brackets-in-patterns).

Comment: mmmm. On this one I have to retort.  What I am referring to is in your documentation. I will edit it to show clarity of what I am speaking to.  In fact, it's where I got the idea in the first place.

Comment: @ChristianMatthew Right. In your example, you can see that a **word** or **punctuation** (or punctuation + letter) is made optional, but not a single character. If you click my link to the UserVoice ticket, you can see that this is currently intentional.

Comment: Again, why does this work for an entity list but not a word that is not an entity list? Also, this works with optional punctuation.  If you think about what I am saying it seems as though the rules are not consistently working.  That to me is the main issues.  It works how it's documented for entity's i.e. `<entity>[[']s]` but not for regular words i.e. `regularWord[[']s]` <<< and that is the main issue I have.  same thing goes for punctuation.  There is no space after a period or question mark but it works as is expected. i.e. `regularWord[(?|.|!)]` works as expected

Comment: @ChristianMatthew I see what you mean. I should note, that a single character actually can be optional per word: `(word[s]|number[s])` vs. `(word|number)[s]`. Really, the point is that it currently can't be done, but if you want this feature, add your support to that UserVoice ticket or create your own.

Comment: I am going to test your example above but i am pretty sure that wasn't working either... And oddly I thought it was working that way which I am completely ok with if that was the case but after intense testing this weekend on our models that functionality seemed to not be working as described in my examples.  I will test again to verify.  But my question to you is, is this more of a bug if it is not working the way you are describing?  To me it might be the case.  If it is a bug would this be able to be fixed?

Comment: @ChristianMatthew You're right..that example doesn't work. Not sure why. Whether or not it's a bug isn't up to me--that's for the LUIS team to decide.

Comment: ok thanks, I appreciate you checking this out.  Would I be able to report this to the LUIS team directly or is this the best channel?  lol the reason why i am asking too is I have created a lot of patterns that used that design pattern and now they don't work...

Comment: UserVoice is the only channel.

Comment: Hi I am going through this today and this seems to be broken or not fully thought out. only an [[']s] works. Specifically `[']` Nothing else can be appended unless it is the apostrophe first. That seems like an odd only working use-case

Comment: Yea, this is kinda of a bad abstraction and the documentation is apart of the issue. but really the usecase is mostly the issue.  the only thing that works arbitrarily is this. `['s]` That's it.  That does not fulfill a pluralization use-case at all.  Not everything is the english language is made plural by appending a `'s` . I really do feel there is a disconnect with this in the documentation and the functionality should be carefully added and explained. Going through 100's of patterns this is a frustrating thing

Comment: @ChristianMatthew I understand. The LUIS team takes all feature requests through [their UserVoice](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/551524-language-understanding-luis?query=Luisuservoice%40microsoft.com). I don't work directly with them and even if I did, the support team doesn't have enough pull to supercede their UserVoice.

Comment: I understand but I have this question. Why does UserVoice supercede what is a perceived bug or defect. I do admit there is a little bit of a complication to that statement of how I am perceiving this to be a bug.  Let me explain what I mean.  The apostrophe is the only character that you can append to the end of word that in the english language makes any sense to a CERTAIN number of scenarios for pluralization.  So as a result, the apostrophe `'` doesn't really help at all except for in that example.  ie. <sample>'s works but <sample>s won't work and <sample>'es makes no sense. This is defect

Comment: @ChristianMatthew I think you and I just differ on whether this should be considered a bug or a feature request. I'll forward this issue to them via email, but I don't expect it to be any faster/better than the UserVoice.

Comment: @ChristianMatthew The reply I got from LUIS was: "The patterns work with tokens not characters. So the pattern you mentioned will fire for "word", "word s", "number" and "number s". If they want increase the confidence of the intents when this pattern fires, they could add a regex entity and add it as a descriptor to the intent. The descriptor part is a new feature that we added to our preview portal in Ignite and they can check it on preview.luis.ai ". They'll file it as a feature request, but priority will be the same as any UserVoice ticket, so no promises on ETA.

Comment: Most of our entities are entity lists. A very large amount. So the regex wouldn't work there.  Also, the idea I have, and if this is what you mean by tokenization is that there would be a "plural or end of word appender" character such as \ and that would take the following statement and append the rest of the word with those characters in an optional format.  i.e. ((car|people|christian)|{entitylist})<\[('s|es|s)>  <==== perfect that right there.